# Problem with Filtering Date on MUI-DataGrid on one specific filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Version details: "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.2.1"

I have a function that creates columns for the DataGrid like below
(only pasting relevant code)

```
if (prop === "date" || prop === "dateModified" || prop === "needByDate") {
      tableColumns.push({
        field: prop,
        headerName: _.startCase(prop),
        type: "date",
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 120,
        align: "left",
        headerAlign: "left",
        valueFormatter: (params) => formatDateAndTime(params.value),
      });
    }
```

The function is passed to the DataGrid like below:

```
 <DataGrid
    rows={data}
    autoHeight={true}
    columns={CreateTableColumns({ data, detailsBool })}
    initialState={{
      pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: pageSize } },
    }}
    pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]}
    onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
    onRowClick={handleRowClick ? (e) => handleRowClick(e) : null}
    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    getRowHeight={() => "auto"}
    disableRowSelectionOnClick
    onCellClick={onCellClick}
    checkboxSelection={checkBoxBool}
    onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
      onRowsSelectionHandler(ids);
    }}
    isRowSelectable={(params) =>
      isRowSelectable === "supplierList" &&
      !(params.row.supplierList.length >= params.row.noOfSamplesRequired)
    }
/>
```

the formateDateAndTime(value) function code is added below:

```
export function formatDateAndTime(prop) {
  var date = new Date(prop);
  var months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ];
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = months[date.getMonth()];
  let dateVal = date.getDate();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let hours = date.getUTCHours() + 4;
  let hour = hours % 12 || 12;
  let formattedDate =
    dateVal +
    "-" +
    month +
    "-" +
    year +
    " " +
    hour +
    ":" +
    minutes +
    `${hours < 12 ? " AM GST" : " PM GST"}`;

  return formattedDate;
}
```

Now the problem im facing is that, the date filter in GridToolbar filters all operators i.e. Date is, is not, is after, is on or after, is on or before, is empty, and is not empty. except one operator - is before.

I have tried using valueGetter and renderCell properties instead of valueFormatter they both give out errors before even displaying the content,
I have also tried deleting my whole colelction of documents and creating new objects to make sure there are no anomalies in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found when apply filter the filterItem value will be 'yyyy-mm-dd'  format; so something like '2024-01-13'

So what you can do is create valueGetter to set the value to be same format
My example

```
## This is my formatter equivalent
export const dateTimeValueFormatter = (value: any) => {
  if (isNumber(value)) return formatDateTimeEpochDays(value);
  try {
    let date = DateTime.fromISO(value);
    if (date.isValid) return date.toFormat('dd/LL/yyyy');

    date = DateTime.fromFormat(value, 'dd/LL/yyyy');
    if (date.isValid) return value;

    return 0;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const dateTimeFilterValueGetter = (value: any) => {
  if (isNumber(value)) return formatDateTimeEpochDays(value, 'yyyy-LL-dd');
  try {
    let date = DateTime.fromISO(value);
    if (date.isValid) return date.toFormat('yyyy-LL-dd');

    date = DateTime.fromFormat(value, 'dd/LL/yyyy');
    if (date.isValid) return date.toFormat('yyyy-LL-dd');

    return 0;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

and for colDef

```
export const dateColDefBase: ColDefType = {
  type: 'date',
  sortingOrder: ['desc', 'asc'],
  sortComparator: dateSortComparator,
  valueGetter: ({ value }) => {
    return dateTimeFilterValueGetter(value);
  },
  valueFormatter: ({ value }) => value && dateTimeValueFormatter(value),
};
```

Generally you can see the how the value in filterItem looks like by using functions like onFilterModelChange, then make sure your valueGetter will return the same format